# Why won't Ubuntu Server 9.04 won't upgrade to 9.10?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, ubuntu-9.04, upgrade

I have a server running 9.04 and I'd like to upgrade it to 9.10 (on the way to getting to the latest version). However, despite following the [nice](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KarmicUpgrades) [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades/Jaunty), I am unable to.

Specifically, `sudo do-release-upgrade` fails:

```
Checking for a new ubuntu release
Done Upgrade tool signature
Done Upgrade tool
Done downloading            
extracting 'lucid.tar.gz'
authenticate 'lucid.tar.gz' against 'lucid.tar.gz.gpg' 
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names

Reading cache

Checking package manager

Can not upgrade 

An upgrade from 'jaunty' to 'lucid' is not supported with this tool.
```

My original /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
## EOL upgrade sources.list
# Required
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jaunty main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jaunty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jaunty-security main restricted universe multiverse

# Optional
#deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jaunty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
#deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jaunty-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
```

Changing `jaunty` to `karmic` and `old-releases` to `releases` gives 404 errors when I run `sudo aptitude update`. And, `sudo do-release-upgrade` still tries to upgrade directly to lucid.

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt-get install update-manager-core`?  Just went through the multiple upgrades required going from 8.10 to 10.04LTS, had no issues.

Comment: I'm not sure but I just tried it now and that didn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably too late but....

> Changing jaunty to karmic and old-releases to releases gives 404 errors

This should be old-releases to *archive*

Comment: It's never too late for a correct answer, especially considering that I haven't marked any answer as correct yet. Testing _archive_ now but already it's looking very good.

Comment: That did the trick. I then had some problems rebooting but [found a work-around](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mountall/+bug/516684/comments/3).

Comment: Happily I've got my 8.04 all the way up to 10.04 now!

Answer (score 3):

This upgrade will not work at all!
From the ubuntu-security-announce mailing list (received last week):

```
This note is just to confirm that the support period for Ubuntu 9.10
(Karmic Koala) formally ended on May 1, 2011 and Ubuntu Security Notices
no longer includes information or updated packages for Ubuntu 9.10.
```

Hence the 404's.

"Cruel workaround": replace all "jaunty" 's in /etc/apt/sources.list and /apt/sources.list.d/* with "lucid" and run "aptitude update && aptitude dist-upgrade"

Comment: Wow, that's very weird especially considering that 9.04, a non-LTS version (right?) is still available, albeit under old-releases, and that 9.10 is available under releases: http://releases.ubuntu.com/karmic/

Comment: Are you looking for some kind of fix to get to "Lucid" or for an explanation..?

Comment: I'm looking for a fix to get to Karmic. Your explanation makes sense but still I find it hard to believe given that older releases are still on `old-releases`. Not your fault, of course!

Answer (score 0):

I see `do-release-upgrade` is automatically trying to upgrade to Lucid, which is wrong (maybe a bug, as the docs don't point out this possibility).

Check `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades`. Does it say `Prompt=lts`? If so, try changing it to `Prompt=normal`.

If all fails you can try upgrading the Debian way - by modifying your sources to point to Karmic and doing `apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Comment: That is what I am trying to do, upgrade to 9.10. I have no clue why it's trying to jump to Lucid.

Comment: Try changing `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` as per the edit, does it help?

Comment: Thanks but it already says `Prompt=normal`.